# Making first scene in Xcode

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to make a game. I understand the concept of scenes but I'm not sure how to implement it. I have this in my Game View Controller:

```
// create a new scene
let scene = SCNScene(named: "main_menu")!
```

I have named the view provided main_menu but I am getting a runtime error whenever I run the app:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: is that the line of code where the fatal error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error demonstrates you're trying to forcefully unwrap an optional that doesn't exist.

Instantiating a `SCNScene(name)` loads a scene from the file with the specified `name` in the app bundle. Make sure your `main_menu` scene exists.

Comment: My problem is that I'm not totally sure how to do that and I can't find any tutorials that seem to address that process in Xcode 7.

Comment: You also need to match the path--include the parent folder, probably scn.assets, in the pathname. The default Xcode 7 SceneKit game template demonstrates this.